# What is this error and how do you resolve? Transaction ID must not be empty

Tags: payment, authorize.net, transaction

Getting an error when submitting a credit card order on Magento site (using Authorize.net payment gateway).

This is the error:

> Transaction ID must not be empty.

Any idea what this error is and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was because the Authorize.net account type was incorrect. Need to update account to a "Card Not Present" account.